# Swapping of cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to Swap the cells in the collection View , I tried couple of samples but was not successful in finding the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'swap the cells'? Do you want to reorder them or do you want replace a type of cell for another?

Comment: check out http://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture